# How to get client ID and secret key from paytm

Tags: paytm

I am trying to do the wallet integration with Paytm. To generate the Oauth token we need to supply the client ID send it by encrypting with client secret key. 
I am struggling to find out how or from where I would get the client ID and secret key from Paytm. The API doc at Paytm says

Oauth APIs

Pre-requisites:
Client Id : Will be provided by paytm for authentication purposes
Client secret : Will be provided by paytm for authentication purposes

http://paywithpaytm.com/developer/paytm_api_doc?target=oauth-apis

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Comment: Have you applied for payment gateway @Vivek Giri ?